# onMouseMove listener only starts receiving events after cursor leaves and re-enters the document

Tags: dart, dart-html, onmousemove

I have CanvasElement which requests pointer lock on click, and then repeatedly passes movementX and movementY to a function using an `onMouseMove` listener (I'm testing first person controls).

It works fine the first time (immediately after page load), but if I press escape and click the canvas again it successfully locks the cursor but doesn't generate a `MouseEvent` to pass to the `onMouseMove` listener.

If I press escape and move the mouse outside of the document (anywhere that's not governed by the markup), move it back into the document and click the canvas, everything works perfectly again.

Any ideas what's causing this odd behaviour?

```dart
_canvas.onMouseMove.listen((MouseEvent e) {
  if (document.pointerLockElement == _canvas) {
    print(e.movement); // debug print
    orientateCamera(e.movement);
  }
});

_canvas.onClick.listen((e) {
  if (document.pointerLockElement == null) {
    _canvas.requestPointerLock();
  }
});
```

All the described behaviour is contained within these lines of code.

Comment: Some code that shows what you try to accomplish might be helpful.

Comment: This example http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/pointerlock/intro/ listens to document mouseevents (so do other examples I found) instead of the element like you do. Have you tried that?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Listening to the document gives the same problems

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what `element.requestPointerLock()` does but
[MDN - Element.requestPointerLock](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.requestPointerLock) states that you should listen to `pointerlockchange` and `pointerlockerror` to see if the request was successful. There is also a `document.exitPointerLock()` which you don't seem to use.

[MDN Pointer Lock API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAPI/Pointer_Lock) seems to be a good introduction.

Comment: There is no ``document.requestPointerLock``

Listening to pointerlockchange and pointerlock error reports no abnormalities.

exitPointerLock() is only needed when you want to use a trigger other than ESC

Comment: I've updated my question significantly, you may want to revise/delete this depending on whether you have/don't have a new suggestion

Comment: Event if it's not a useful answer to your question, I think the links are helpful for others who might stumble upon your question. I guess it's a bug in Dart or the Browser. You should probably file a bug.

Comment: No problems, I just didn't want your answer to seem irrelevant because of me